# SSD1306 OLED Temperature Degree Symbol

Tags: c, esp32

does anyone know how to add the temperature degree symbol to a font file. I am working with an ESP32 using a 128x32 OLED and a 7x10 font to display the characters.
I have been searching but without much success. Thank you.

```
 static const uint16_t Font7x10 [] = {
0x1000, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x7C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // A
0x7800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x7800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x7800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // B
0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // C
0x7000, 0x4800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4800, 0x7000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // D
0x7C00, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x7C00, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x7C00, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // E
0x7C00, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x7800, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // F
0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x5C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // G
0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x7C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // H
0x3800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // I
0x0400, 0x0400, 0x0400, 0x0400, 0x0400, 0x0400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // J
0x4400, 0x4800, 0x5000, 0x6000, 0x5000, 0x4800, 0x4800, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // K
0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x7C00, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // L
0x4400, 0x6C00, 0x6C00, 0x5400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // M
0x4400, 0x6400, 0x6400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x4C00, 0x4C00, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // N
0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // O
0x7800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x7800, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // P
0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x5400, 0x3800, 0x0400, 0x0000,  // Q
0x7800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x7800, 0x4800, 0x4800, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // R
0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4000, 0x3000, 0x0800, 0x0400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // S
0x7C00, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // T
0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // U
0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // V
0x4400, 0x4400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x6C00, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // W
0x4400, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // X
0x4400, 0x4400, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // Y
0x7C00, 0x0400, 0x0800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2000, 0x4000, 0x7C00, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // Z
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3800, 0x4400, 0x3C00, 0x4400, 0x4C00, 0x3400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // a
0x4000, 0x4000, 0x5800, 0x6400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x6400, 0x5800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // b
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // c
0x0400, 0x0400, 0x3400, 0x4C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4C00, 0x3400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // d
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3800, 0x4400, 0x7C00, 0x4000, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // e
0x0C00, 0x1000, 0x7C00, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // f
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3400, 0x4C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4C00, 0x3400, 0x0400, 0x7800,  // g
0x4000, 0x4000, 0x5800, 0x6400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // h
0x1000, 0x0000, 0x7000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // i
0x1000, 0x0000, 0x7000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xE000,  // j
0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4800, 0x5000, 0x6000, 0x5000, 0x4800, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // k
0x7000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // l
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x7800, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // m
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x5800, 0x6400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // n
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3800, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // o
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x5800, 0x6400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x6400, 0x5800, 0x4000, 0x4000,  // p
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3400, 0x4C00, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4C00, 0x3400, 0x0400, 0x0400,  // q
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x5800, 0x6400, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x4000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // r
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x3800, 0x4400, 0x3000, 0x0800, 0x4400, 0x3800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // s
0x2000, 0x2000, 0x7800, 0x2000, 0x2000, 0x2000, 0x2000, 0x1800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // t
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x4C00, 0x3400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // u
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // v
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x5400, 0x6C00, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // w
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4400, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x2800, 0x4400, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // x
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4400, 0x4400, 0x2800, 0x2800, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x6000,  // y
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x7C00, 0x0800, 0x1000, 0x2000, 0x4000, 0x7C00, 0x0000, 0x0000,  // z
};
```

Comment: Without ever having seen such a device, I would suspect that the values you have here are bitfields stating which LED digits are on and which are off.

Comment: This is a bitmapped font. The comments on the right show that there is one line per character. Each line has 10 elements (one per each of 10 rows) and each element has 7 bits (9 are unused). IDK why they used 16-bit and not 8-bit. Add more rows to the table for `0..9` and `°` and any punctuation characters needed. Figure out the patterns on paper. If you don't know the bit correspondence, you can reverse-engineer that from the existing table characters.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, i managed to do it.